# Locate certain part of a page by appending HTML element to URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url

I know that add `#` sign with the HTML element id will direct the user to the location of the element when user click the link. I don't know that much why it is the case, Javasript or Jquery? is it a website specific feature or it is actually a general rule across all pages.

Here is an example:

```
https://docs.python.org/2/library/gl.html
# the following one will direct to the certain title
https://docs.python.org/2/library/gl.html#module-GL
```

Now I have a page (Click [Here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects.htm#Data%20Hiding:)) that I want to append certain criteria so when I send that link to people, they will start from the `Data-hiding` session instead of the top of the page.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> I don't know that much why it is the case, Javasript or Jquery?

No. It is a basic feature of [urls](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/intro.html#h-2.1.2) and [HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.1).

> The destination anchor of a link may be an element within an HTML
>   document. The destination anchor must be given an anchor name and any
>   URI addressing this anchor must include the name as its fragment
>   identifier.
>
> Destination anchors in HTML documents may be specified either by the A
>   element (naming it with the name attribute), or by any other element
>   (naming with the id attribute).

---

> Is it possible to do that for other attribute like header text.

Not without using JavaScript to examine the URL, find the matching element and scroll to it.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is a *link to element*, and works only if the element has the given `id` attribute.

For example, this

```
<h1 id="fubar">Fuu Bar</h1>
```

will work with `index.html#fubar`

Without having access to editing the linked page, if there is no such `id` attribute on the element you want to link, there is no way to do this kind of linking.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the corresponding `id` on the header tag you target :

```
<h2 id="data-hiding">Data Hiding:</h2>
```

The link would be http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects.htm#data-hiding

Comment: that is not my website and there is no `id` attribute for that tag. Is it still possible to navigate in that case?

Comment: Then it all comes down to the point where you cannot do what you are trying to do : ) sorry